What is the difference between goto("") and goto("/") in Playwright
I have a baseUrl setup in my playwright.config file.
I've noticed that page.goto("") and page.goto("/") both navigates to the base-url itself.
Is there any difference between these two behaviors?

None that I'm aware of. What is your use case, and what baseURL do you have set up in your config?

Without any relation to a specific use-case or a specific URL. It happens with any url at any given test.

If a baseURL is provided via the context options, it all boils down to what the WEB API’s URL does because Page.goto() uses it under the hood.

Page.goto() [playwright.dev]
url string
URL to navigate page to. The url should include scheme, e.g. https://. When a baseURL via the context options was provided and the passed URL is a path, it gets merged via the new URL() constructor.

So what does the WEB API’s URL do with a baseURL and "" or "/"?
It runs the algorithm outlined by the specification and either throws or returns a value and in this case, the value returned is the baseURL used. [1]
So to answer your question; no there is no difference in behaviour between the two because the WEB API’s URL algorithm parses them the same way.

[1] For brevity, I won’t go into detail about the algorithm because it is beyond the scope of the question but if the reader wishes to study the algorithm, it is a part of the specification at whatwg.org.
